# Why sum() doesn't work on array of bytes elements in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, byte

This code works perfectly:

```
b'\x4a' + b'\x20'
b'J '
```

But this doesn't:

```
sum([b'\x4a', b'\x20'])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'bytes'
```

Why? How to concatenate many `bytes` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` instead:

```
b''.join([b'\x4a', b'\x20'])
```

Output:

```
b'J '
```

Comment: Can... and *should*. It's possible to trick `sum` into doing it, but it's still inefficient.

Comment: @KellyBundy how? I got  ```TypeError: sum() can't sum bytes [use b''.join(seq) instead]``` when I tried to trick ```sum```

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) says "the **start** value is not allowed to be a string", so... use a [non-string start value](https://tio.run/##JcmxCoAgGEXh3ae4mwoOUQ3R2GtUiKVRUCa/BvX0RrQdvhOetJ6@agLlPO8mRnQtA6xboLWxVmsR3b4onGl1JL8HkEsX@Z8YC7T5JOJ1iH7iw10brvBFWfBRoRNSypxf).

Comment: `sum([b'\x4a', b'\x20'], start=b'')` gives `TypeError: sum() can't sum bytes [use b''.join(seq) instead]`, so a bytes start value won't work anyway.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Which is why I used something else.

Comment: @Nin17 ~ Nothing to it. Just do this `sum(map(lambda b:int.from_bytes(b, 'little'), [b'\x4a', b'\x20'])).to_bytes(1,'little')` :D :D :D

Comment: @OneMadGypsy That doesn't work. Did you not test it?

Comment: @KellyBundy ~ Yes it does work. Yes I tested it (and again after you claimed it didn't). Also, it's obvious it will work. it's mapping bytes to an int and passing it to sum. Why would you think that doesn't work? However, regardless if it does or doesn't work (it does). It was posted with a lot of sarcasm as far as answers go.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Because I've read it and because **I** actually tested it. It results in `b'j'` instead of `b'J '`.

Comment: @KellyBundy ~ HAH! Good eye! You got me. I missed that fine detail. Probably need to change to big endain or something. It can work.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy You'd also have to multiply with powers of 256.

Comment: @KellyBundy ~ the thing is, I'm not wrong. The sum of those bytes is `b'j'`. The user doesn't want a sum, though. I'm not sure why they were using sum to **concat** a list of bytes. Essentially `sum([74,32])`

Comment: @OneMadGypsy They made it clear that `b'J '` is the desired result.

Comment: Ok, concat with sum `sum(int.from_bytes(b,'little')<<(i<<3) for i,b in enumerate(bt)).to_bytes(len(bt),'little')`. `bt` is the list of bytes.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Yes, that works, at least if all elements have length 1. I'd say it doesn't "trick" `sum` into doing "it" (summing an "array of bytes elements"), though (unlike mine, which really does). You're using `sum` for summing numbers instead, which is what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually had no choice but to use `sum`, this is one way you could do it. This iterates over the `bytes`, converting them to `ints` and bit-shifting each one to the next `byte`. Then it `sums` all of those `ints` and coverts the `sum` back to `bytes`.

This isn't meant to be the "best" answer. It's the "how to do it with sum" answer. You probably shouldn't use this. It's a little bit clever, because it stores the byte length as it goes, and is therefore never wrong or needing a final equation to determine it (as long as your `list` is of single `bytes`).

```
from typing import Iterable

def sum_concat_bytelist(bl:Iterable, e:str='little') -> bytes:
    return sum(int.from_bytes(b,e)<<((l:=i)<<3) for i,b in enumerate(bl)).to_bytes(l+1,e)
```

If you wanted to be able to use `bytes` of any length at each `list` index, you have to make some modifications. This version eliminates `enumerate` and manages the `i` manually.

```
from typing import Iterable

def sum_concat_bytelist(bl:Iterable, e:str='little') -> bytes:
    i, l = 0, lambda n,i: (((n.bit_length()+7)//8)<<3)+i #total current bits forced to multiples of 8
    #                      use last `i`---v v---store next `i`
    return sum((n:=int.from_bytes(b,e))<<(i,i:=l(n,i))[0] for b in bl).to_bytes((i+7)//8,e)
        
print(sum_concat_bytelist([b'\x20\x4a',b'\x4a\x20']))
```

Both of these ways are probably about as good as it's going to get for what they are, but at best, I would consider this just an experiment. Using `.join` is the way to go.